# Laravel Progressive web app

Tags: laravel-5, progressive-web-apps

how we can create multiple progressive web app from same website for each page.  I want to know about how the chrome is going to know whether progressive web app for the website already install or not

Answer (score 0):

how we can create multiple progressive web app from same website for each page ?

Think about progressive web apps in the same way you think about native applications. Then think if makes sense to have separated applications and you'll get your answer.

Being specific with your question I think you distinguish between some kind of info pages and service pages you currently keep under the same domain. If this is so, be aware that progressive web apps are unique by origin (protocol + domain name + port) and need HTTPS enabled so keeping separated progressive web apps can incur in additional infrastructure costs.

Nevertheless, this does not mean the same teams you have now can not maintain different parts of the same application

now how the chrome is going to know whether progressive web app for the website already install or not ?

This will work is done by service worker